# javaFX circle in a layout not visible

Tags: java, css, javafx

I made a circle and added as a child to a group. then I added the group as a child to a layout(Region). I added Region to the scene. I made both with different colours but I cannot see the circle

**Analog_clock.java**

```
package analog_clock;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Analog_clock extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setCenterX(100.0f);
        circle.setCenterY(100.0f);
        circle.setRadius(50.0f);
        circle.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);

        Group g = new Group();
        g.getChildren().add(circle);

        Background_region_ bg = new Background_region_();
        bg.getChildrenUnmodifiable().add(g);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bg, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Background_Region_.java**

```
package analog_clock;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Background_region_ extends Region 
{
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Background_region_()
    {
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ACACE6");
    }

}
```

**style.css**

```
.circle{-fx-stroke: #cdd0d7;}
```

Comment: just want to know anything wrong with my method? I can check the code myself

Comment: edited question added code

Comment: @Yahya can you please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `Region` Class only has an **Unmodifiable List** of children via its public API, that means, the only way to add children to it is to subclass it (e.g `Pane`). So use `Pane` or another subclass, something like this for example:

```
Pane bg = new Pane();
bg.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.web("#ACACE6"), null,null)));
bg.getChildren().add(g);
```

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999779/javafx-my-css-file-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Use Pane instead of Region. Region is a special parent class for control's developers.

Next line throws exception in your code:

```
bg.getChildrenUnmodifiable().add(g);
```

Note word "Unmodifiable". It means your are not supposed and can't modify this list.

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999779/javafx-my-css-file-is-not-working